# Netcat working on Linux but not on mac terminal

Tags: networking, terminal, netcat

When I run

```
nc -l 2399
```

on my mac it doesn't work, regardless of what device I'm trying to connect to on. I run

```
nc 192.168.1.24 2399
```

and it just prompts me for the next input.
When I start the listen with the Linux device it works fine.
Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Details please. You've got a Mac and a Linux-based machine? What are the IP addresses of each? What do you mean that "_it just prompts me for the next input_"? What does? Do you mean the command ends immediately and you get the next shell prompt? What if you add `-vvv` to the caller? Which version(s) of `netcat` have you got installed? On Linux-based systems there are usually two to choose from

Comment: Add -p to your command:   nc -l -p 2399

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi that's one of the variations between the two `nc` commands. One requires `-p` and maybe even a listen address, but the other doesn't

Comment: @BruceMalaudzi using the -p argument worked! Thank you

Comment: @YassineElshayeb please accept the answer and upvote. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Add -p to your command:

```
nc -l -p 2399
```